# Given $s=\int_0^33t\sqrt{t^2+16}\,dt$ show that $s=61$

Tags: definite-integrals

I decided to use U-substitution to show that $s=61$ but have failed. Here is my working, where have I gone wrong? Regards Tom
$$s=\int_0^33t\sqrt{t^2+16}\,dt$$
$$u=t^2+16$$
$$du=2tdt\Rightarrow3(\frac{du}{2})=3tdt$$
$$t=3\Rightarrow(3)^2+16=25$$
$$t=0\Rightarrow(0)^2+16=16$$
$$s=\int_{16}^{25}(\sqrt{u})(3(\frac{du}{2}))$$
$$s=\frac32\int_{16}^{25}(\sqrt{u})du$$
$$s=\frac32\int_{16}^{25}u^{1/2}du$$
$$s=\frac32\left[\frac{u^{3/2}}{\frac32}\right]_{16}^{25}$$
$$s=\frac32\left[\frac23u^{3/2}\right]_{16}^{25}$$
$$s=\frac32\left[\frac23(t^2+16)^{3/2}\right]_{16}^{25}$$
$$s=\frac32\left[\frac23((25)^2+16)^{3/2})\right]-\frac32\left[\frac23((16)^2+16)^{3/2})\right]$$

$$(=11742.884....)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flaw is in substituting $t$ back in. For one thing, you don't need to do this, and for another, you didn't change the limits back. If you go
$$ s= \frac{3}{2} \left[ \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} \right]_{16}^{25} = [u^{3/2}]_{16}^{25}, $$
then you get
$$ 25^{3/2} - 16^{3/2} = 5^3-4^3 = 125-64=61. $$

Answer (score 1):

OK up to

$$
s=\frac32\left[\frac23u^{3/2}\right]_{16}^{25}
$$

but then you have kept the revised limits of integration (for $u$) when you revert back to $t$ as the variable:

$$
s=\frac32\left[\frac23(t^2+16)^{3/2}\right]_{16}^{25}
$$